# What is a coordinate-free version of Noethers theorem?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

- What are some examples and derivations of some basic symmetries (not coordinate symmetries)?

For example I remember a sufficient condition for being a symmetry of the lagrangian system is being an exact Cartan symmetry.

I wouldn't really want to jump into jet bundles, a formulation on sypmletic / preympletic spaces would suffice.

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider to only ask 1 subquestion per post and to avoid list-type subquestions (basically because they don't have unique answers that it make sense to vote on), i.e. remove the last subquestion.

Comment: Can't post a full answer now, but you should look into the geometry of jet bundles. The book "Introduction to global variational geometry" by Krupka is a fairly didactic reference.

Comment: There is only one subquestion...

Comment: The question is about the abstract definition, subquestion about an example.

Comment: 1 subquestion in the title and 1 subquestion in the main text is still 2 subquestions.

Comment: While I personally disagree with the closure of this question (I think it is clear that you want to know how Noether's theorem looks like geometrically, and that's it), you won't get any results by being so aggressive.

Comment: Exactly, just plane simple geometrical formulation, which fundamentally is how the theorem should be in the first place... I'll work it out myself..

Comment: Seems to me that this is still largely a list-based question (asking for examples/derivations), rather than a question about a concept.

Comment: The question could not be more plain and simple. Just asking for a basic physics theorem that for some bizarre reason does not have an invarint formulation..

Answer (score 0):

"If you change something but the Lagrangian does not change, something else is conserved"